# Birt integration in JHipster application

Tags: birt, jhipster

I'm fairly new to Jhipster and angularjs and i'm trying to integrate the Birt engine in a JHipster application using an H2 embedeed database.
I found [this page](https://spring.io/blog/2012/01/30/spring-framework-birt) that details how to integrate the birt engine in a spring application but i don't to how to applicate this for my application.

Here are the modifications performed in the jhipster project:

- add dependency to org.eclipse.birt.runtime in pom
- Create the classes Car, CarServiceImpl, BirtView, BirtEngineFactory and BirtDataServiceConfiguration in a sub-package report as described in the article.
- I added the BirtWebConfiguration class in the sub-package config. I removed the @ComponentScan line that is already taken into account in the Application class.
- I created an empty report in src/main/webapp/reports/toto.rptdesign

My problems are:

- When accessing the application main page a "PageNotFound exception" with the following message "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'". 
   I presume this is due to the BirtWebConfiguration that seems to overwritte the rest path configuration. 

  How shall I define a new rest end-point /reports ?
- When accessing the http://localhost:8080/reports page, a thymeleaf exception is raised
  `[ERROR] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-nio-127.0.0.1-8090-exec-5] Exception processing template "birtView": Error resolving template "birtView", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
  [ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "birtView", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause
  org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "birtView", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
  at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:245) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I used the same article to integrate BIRT with JHipster, and it worked fine (except that the URL is public and not integrated with security). Specifically, can you describe the problem you are having?

Comment: Hi Rori.  I'v just edited my question to detail the problems i'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has the BirtView bean been created? For example, in config/LocaleConfiguration.java:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/reports").setViewName("birtView");
}

@Bean 
public BirtView birtView(){ 
    BirtView birtView = new BirtView(); 
    birtView.setDataSource(dataSource);
    birtView.setAppContext(applicationContext);
    birtView.setBirtEngine(this.engine().getObject());
    return birtView; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rori, it works for me now. My problem was in the BirtWebConfiguration. The annotations ComponentScan and EnableWebMvc shall be removed. What's the use of setting the applicationContext in the BirtView? I thought it was already done thanks to the BirtEngineFactory.setApplicationContext() method.